# How do I store 262144 varibles efficiently? Multi-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, tree

I'm trying to write a program that reads a .txt file containing several thousand strings (each one is exactly 9 letters long) made up only of the letters A,C,G and T (i.e. DNA sequences).

Now, there are of course 4^9 possible combinations of A,C,G and T in a 9-letter string. I need to know how often each of these 262144 combinations appears in my .txt file.

My problem is that I (obviously) don't want to initialize 262144 individual variables, increment each when a match is found and then print them all individually, because that would be crazy.

So, my idea was to create either some kind of tree which goes down the branches according to the letter encountered at each node and stores the number of times each branch was 'run down' (i.e. each possible 9-letter combination) at the last node.

Or an array of 262144 positions where I can store the number of appearances of each possible combination. For that, however, I would need some kind of non-redundant system that chooses a unique position in the array (to store the number of times that combination has been encountered) based on which letters have been encountered in which sequence in the 9-letter string.

For example: For each 'A' encountered in the 9-letter string, I increment my 'pointer variable' (which points to the position in the big array) by 0, so every time the sequence AAAAAAAAA is encountered, position [0] of my array is incremented by 1. For every 'T' I increment the pointer by 1, so TTTTTTTTT would increment position [9] of my array by 1 and so on.

This, however, gives me the problem that both sequences AAAAAAAAT and TAAAAAAAA (and all other combinations of 8 As and 1T) will increment position [1] of the array. So I would have to use some kind of system where the pointer can actually reach each value between 0 and 262143 exactly once?

I'm sure there is some better way? Multi-dimensional arrays or something like that?

Best regards,
rokyo

Comment: You might start getting answers as soon as (a) you specify which programming language you are using, and (b) you show some effort or example of what you tried yourself. In general I would suggest a GroupBy combined with a Count.

Comment: The most efficient method of storing so many variables should be independent from any language, right?

Answer (score 2):

You want to store this as a tree of depth 9, each node can have 4 children, just each of the 4 possibilities of the next letter. Each leaf would have a counter in it. When you have built your tree, go through all the leaves and that will give you the counts.

So it would work like this:
Read in a sequence.
For each character in the sequence select the proper child, if it does not exist create the node. If it does then go to the child.
If you are at the end of you string then update the count in the node.
loop back to read in a sequence.

Once all sequences are read, and tree is built.
Iterate through the tree, if it is a leaf (no children) then spit out the count.

The benefit to this approach is if the size of the data changes, or the length of each sequence it will still work. This is a typical use for a tree.

Comment: I really like the flexibility to change the sequence length without having to change any code! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why multidimensional. If you want to count just encode into an integer and increment the place in an array of 262143 integers.

How to encode your string: think of those 4 letters as a binary number with 2 places. so you need 18 bits to represent one combination.

```
A - 00
C - 01
G - 10
T - 11

AAAAAAAAA - 000000000000000000
ACACACACA - 000100010001000100  - 17476
GAAAAAAAA - 100000000000000000  - 131072
TAAAAAAAA - 110000000000000000  - 196608
AAAAAAAAT - 000000000000000011  - 3
```

The Array in Memory would be depending on the maximum number of occurrences you want to cope with. If 4 Billion is enough you would need about a megabyte of memory to represent this "counter"-array.

Each counting access would be O(1).

Comment: Now THAT is memory efficient! I would have never had the idea to encode it as binary. Thanks a lot!